# PHP MD5 not working in if statement

Tags: php, if-statement, md5

I'm having problems comparing a submitted password and one thats called from the database. Both equal the same output but when compared in an if statement they apparently don't equal each other

```
    <?php
    session_start();
include("../functions.php");
connect();

$userPinLogin = $_REQUEST['pinLogin'];
$userEmailLogin = $_REQUEST['emailLogin'];
$i = session_id();
$findPin = md5($userPinLogin);


$checkUserDetails =  mysql_query("SELECT * FROM agentLogins WHERE email = '$userEmailLogin' AND pin = '$findPin' ")
or die(mysql_error());
while($checkUserDetailsResults = mysql_fetch_array($checkUserDetails))
{
    $testUserPin = $checkUserDetailsResults['pin']; 
    $userLinkId = $checkUserDetailsResults['linkId'];   
    $testUserEmail = $checkUserDetailsResults['email']; 
}


if (empty($testUserPin))
{

header ("Location: http://www.propertyclouduk.co.uk/agentPortal/index.php?er=pass");

}

if ($findPin == $testUserPin)
{
    echo "all match";


}

else
{
    echo "none match";
}


?>
```

both
findPin & testUserPin = ad0234829205b9033196ba818f7a872b 
but in the if statement the statement comes up false saying they don't match

Comment: Can you `var_dump($findPin, $testUserPin);` and post the output?

Comment: You don't need to do this secondary check, your MySQL will only return a row if its a match.

Comment: output is: string(32) "ad0234829205b9033196ba818f7a872b" string(33) "ad0234829205b9033196ba818f7a872b "

Comment: The second one has a space at the end, you need to `trim()` them

Comment: Rather than trimming anything, I'd try to find out why hashes are stored incorrectly in the first place. In any case: 1) Plain MD5 hashes don't add a lot of security (you can even google many of them). 2) Since the site user can build his own SQL code, it's trivial to log into the site anyway 3) The mysql extension is deprecated—if you don't know that, it means you've never checked the PHP manual.

Answer (score 2):

you should not use md5 for hashing passwords as it has been cracked,use bcrypt instead its much safer

usage of BCRYPT

on register page---

```
$pass = "the users password";
$secure_pass = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);;//the secured hashed pass
```

on the login page ----

```
$pass_by_user="the password entered by the user in the login page";
$pass_in_db= "the users password retrieved from the mysql table using the email or other non sensitive data";
$correct_pass= password_verify($pass_by_user, $pass_in_db);//comparison of the password in the database and the entered password
```

Comment: Absolutely true, and good advice, but not an answer to the question, so should probably be a comment instead.

Comment: But it's sad to see newbies waste so much effort in learning obsolete libraries and implementing low-security. It's like spending the whole day in the kitchen to cook mud.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario yeah true that its infact a bit annoying and also sad

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the loop goes on untill `checkUserDetailsResults` is `null`.

At that point, your check will obviously fail.

If you are certain that the couple `(email,pin)` is unique in that table, you don't need a loop because you will have only one result, so you can test it like so:

```
$result =  mysql_query("SELECT * FROM agentLogins WHERE email = '$userEmailLogin' AND pin = '$findPin' ")
or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
// mysql_fetch_array will return null if no row is found
if($row){
  // We got a match, the check here will succeed
  $testUserPin = $row['pin'];
  $userLinkId = $row['linkId'];
  $testUserEmail = $row['email'];

  if ($findPin == $testUserPin){
    echo "all match";
  }else{
    echo "none match";
  }
}else{
  // No match found, redirect
  header ("Location: http://www.propertyclouduk.co.uk/agentPortal/index.php?er=pass");
  die;
}
```